# Objective-C Threading: Exiting a thread, retain problems

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

I'm trying to create a thread that configures a run loop to run a physics engine through a defined NSTimer. However, I'm having trouble making the thread exit normally (or I think the problem is).

Attached are the relevant portions of my code:

(This code is in a view controller)
(back is called when a button is pressed)

```
- (void)back {

    [timestep invalidate];
    exiting = YES;

    [self release];

}

- (void)initializePhysicsWorld {

    // Initializes the thread to simulate physics interactions.
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(physicsThreadMethod)
                             toTarget:self
                           withObject:nil];
}

- (void)physicsThreadMethod {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSRunLoop *myRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

    timestep = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f/60.0f
                                       target:self
                                     selector:@selector(step:)
                                     userInfo:nil
                                      repeats:YES];

    [myRunLoop addTimer:timestep forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    while (!exiting) {

        CFRunLoopRun();

        [pool release];
        pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; // periodically refreshes pool
    }
    CFRunLoopStop([myRunLoop getCFRunLoop]);
    NSLog(@"Thread is going to exit");
    [pool release];

}

- (void)dealloc {
    if ([self.view superview]) {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [super dealloc];
}
```

The engine (the step: function) runs fine, but when I try to exit the loop by running the method back, it would appear that the thread does not release its retain on my view controller (dealloc is not called). I think my thread didn't exit the physicsThreadMethod method as the NSLog does not appear in the console. Dealloc was only called when I run 'back' a second time.

I'm not really sure why this is happening, so I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in here:

```
while (!exiting) {

    CFRunLoopRun(); //<-- here you start the run loop.
    // the lines under this line are NEVER executed. also the while loop does nothing
    [pool release];
    pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; // periodically refreshes pool
}
```

You could use `NSOperations` to wrap your work, there are already properties defined on this class to do exactly this kind of thing.

If you want to stick with your implementation in a `NSThread` you have to take a look at the `CFRunLoop` [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html) and how to add observers to the run loop.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the CFRunLoopRun() to `[myRunLoop runUntilDate:]` and now it works, except that there's a delay based on the interval I placed at the NSDate parameter. I guess this isn't the most elegant solution but I'll make do with it now.. I'll read up on NSOperations. :)

Comment: Thanks the answer was helpful, flag it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does CFRunLoopRun return every step:? CFRunLoopStop or [myRunLoop runUntilDate:] would help.

Comment: Yep, I realised that CFRunLoopRun does not return. I've changed it to
`[myRunLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]]`
But it still doesn't appear to be working, except that the code in the while loop now runs. I think the current problem is that `[self release]` is called before the thread exits.

Comment: self is retained from NSThread and NSTimer. So [self release] affects only to reduce retainCount of self.

Comment: How about "volatile BOOL exiting;"?

Comment: I've managed to let the thread run to completion after using `myRunLoop runUntilDate:` :) And I got the timer to release the reference through `[timestep invalidate]`, so all is well now. Thanks so much!